# Crontab influences bash script if condition?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scripting

I am a bit baffled here, and not really sure how to debug this. I have a self-written bash script, that checks if a samba share is active, and if not, sends me an email.

Script is in /root/SKRIPTS/, permission looks like this:

```
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel   281 Nov  8 08:54 test_samba_shares.sh
-rwx------   1 root  wheel    39 Nov  7 13:56 smbclient.cred
```

Content of the .sh script is this:

```
smbclient -L 10.0.0.1 -A /root/SKRIPTS/smbclient.cred | grep -q Backup

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo "Backup_* mounted, nothing to do"
else
    echo "Subject: Samba has failed" | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v mail@localmail.server
fi

return 1;
```

/etc/crontab looks like this (entry only)

```
10 1 * * * root /root/SKRIPTS/test_samba_shares.sh
```

The thing is, if I, as root, run this, it works flawlessly. But every night I get an email that samba has failed, indicating that the cron script somehow trips into the else path. How can this be? Am I missing something obvious here? What would be the best way to debug this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: First thing, if you what to make sure your bash script is being interpreted by bash, make `#!/bin/bash` the first line in the script. Otherwise cron may be executing the script under `/bin/sh` which may not link to bash and will certainly not give you all the features as `/bin/bash`.

Comment: For further troubleshooting, start with [the `cron` tag's info page](https://serverfault.com/tags/cron/info)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sometimes, cron jobs don't run with the `$PATH` that you might be expecting. First and foremost, I would try fully-qualifying the path to your `smbclient` executable, just to eliminate that as a possibility. Or, explicitly export your `PATH` in the wrapper script that's called by cron.

Comment: You can also set the PATH environment variable in the crontab file itself (but be sure to put that before the item you want it to apply to).

Comment: That was it, thanks a lot! I will keep the PATH issue in mind for the next scripts, greatly appreciated.